# how to enable JSONP calls in JQUERY using .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: jquery, jsonp, wcf-client, webservice-client

what do i need to do for invoke cross-domain reference using 3.5 framework? i learned that JSONP support by default in 4.0 framework.

what is the alternative any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what framework or what environment you're using. As long as your web page returns a **VALID JAVASCRIPT** object wrapped in a function you're doing JSONP.

Make your web page returns something like:

```
func({"foo":"bar"});
```

Comment: can you please help out this, i have been struggling this from few days and i havent found any good explanation, i did not understand what you mean by func({"foo":"bar"});